# Where to store automated tests in source control

Tags: version-control, tfs, automated-tests

My company recently started getting up to date on the usage of TFS, source control, and branching strategies. Our current branching strategy is the basic 'Dev > Main > Release' method, which works well for our small team. However, the issue lies with our automated tests. All of our integration tests and UI tests are written in C# and executed in a nightly build process. In effort to keep source clean and well kept, where exactly should we place the automated  test code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could place the automated tests inside of each branch. Your automated tests can be merged and treated just like regular code since it will be changing for new development.

The other option could be for you to place it where your projects build-types and build files reside.

It is important to make sure it is checked into source control.

Comment: Makes sense. Also this way we can look back several builds and view the changes in the test code as well. Thanks!

Comment: More than just "could" - this is a "should", maybe even a "must".  Your tests and your application are tightly coupled, and need to be versioned together.